# Unable to put integer variable with with time variable in solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm creating a contract in solidity in which I want to take input of number of days for which, he want to pause sell/purchase but I'm unable to attach the local variable with any time variable, as it's giving me error:

```
**from solidity:
ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'days'
   --> Marketplace.sol:171:57:
    |
171 |                 endHold = block.timestamp + daystohold1 days;**
```

Kindly tell me if there's a solution or alternative for this. I'm also attaching the relevant piece of code from the contract.

```
 function setFormula(uint256 fromPrice1, uint256 toPrice1, uint256 daystohold1,
    uint256 fromPrice2, uint256 toPrice2, uint256 daystohold2,
    uint256 fromPrice3, uint256 toPrice3,  uint256 daystohold3,
     uint256 elsedaystohold4) public onlyOwner {

            if(getLastPrice <= fromPrice1 && getLastPrice <=toPrice1){
                onHold = true;
                endHold = block.timestamp + daystohold1 days;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly you cannot convert in day. as you have used uint256 days. but you need to do like this.

```
endHold= blobk.timestamp  +  (daystohold1 * 1 day);
```